# CSS how to target element beside my current element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

If I have 2 elements side-by-side in the DOM like this:

```
a.button
div.container
```

I want to target `a.button` **if** `div.container` has class `div.container.fullscreen`

I was thinking something like this:

`div.container.fullscreen + a.button { display:none }`, but it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you write out the html so we can get a clearer idea of what you're working with?

Comment: Try to ckeck this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector

Comment: is button used to get div full screen ? if yes, then there might be a solution. Your HTML markup plz :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`+` won't work as it's the **next** sibling selector.

Your selector `div.container.fullscreen + a.button` would target the `a` if that was the **next immediate sibling** of the `div`, e.g.

```
div.container.fullscreen
a.button // this is now targeted
```

`div.container.fullscreen ~ a.button` won't work either as that'll select all the siblings after, and not before.

```
a.button // this isn't targeted.
div.container.fullscreen
a.button // this is now targeted
a.button // so is this
```

Sadly, there is no previous sibling selector to achieve what you want using pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The `E + F` syntax only matches if `E` precedes `F`. If they are ordered like you just described, I don't think you can style the `a` with pure CSS.

You might simply change the HTML to put the `fullscreen` class on the parent container of both `container` and `button`. That way, you can use the following declarations to style:

```
.fullscreen > div.container {
  /* 
    any fullscreen modifications to be done, what used to be in div.fullscreen
  */
}

.fullscreen > a.button {
  display: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

missing your real html. `<a>` has an `href` attribute ? Is it targetting `<div>` ?

Button doesn't have necessary to be hidden if it stands hidden under div once full expanded , it 's being hidden by div itself.

Form elements can help see idea in action :
http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/otFim